# Ubuntu 14.04 Trying to Set Login Screen and Gsettings Fails with Error

Tags: unity, bash, lightdm

Following instructions in other posts that involve dconf-editor or using su lightdm -s /bin/bash, I hit a big hurdle with the following error:

```
olefoxx@Don-L355n2:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for olefoxx:
root@Don-L355n2:~# su lightdm -s /bin/bash
lightdm@Don-L355n2:/root$ gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'false'

(process:6671): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=1ce09697f64a0624d8339a0b562cefd9 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1
lightdm@Don-L355n2:/root$
```

So what's my next step?  Incidently, this is a complete reinstall of Ubuntu 14.04.2 with all updates applied.

Comment: Does `su lightdm -s /bin/bash -` help? Note the `-` at the end.